# Syntax error when attempting to run tests with page-object included

Tags: page-object-gem

I've recently picked up the page-object gem, but I've been unable to get my tests (based on Cucumber/Selenium) to run when this gem is included.

According to gem list, I have the gem installed:

```
page-object (0.9.1)
```

My env.rb file includes:

```
require 'page-object'
```

However when I attempt to run my tests, I receive the following error:

> /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/page-object-0.9.1/lib/page-object/widgets.rb:32: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting '|'
>   ...dget_tag do |name, identifier={:index => 0}, &block|
>                                 ^
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/page-object-0.9.1/lib/page-object/widgets.rb:32: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting kEND
>   ...ame, identifier={:index => 0}, &block|
>                                 ^
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/page-object-0.9.1/lib/page-object/widgets.rb:122: syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting $end (SyntaxError)
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `gem_original_require'
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in`require'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/page-object-0.9.1/lib/page-object.rb:10
>   />Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:116:in `gem_original_require'
>   />Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:116:in`require'
>   /Users/garethbragg/dev/trade-finder/test/cucumber/features/support/env.rb:6
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.3.5/bin/../lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:122:in `load'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.3.5/bin/../lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:122:in`load_code_file'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.3.5/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:180:in `load_file'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.3.5/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in`load_files!'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.3.5/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `each'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.3.5/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in`load_files!'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.3.5/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:183:in `load_step_definitions'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.3.5/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:42:in`run!'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.3.5/bin/../lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:47:in `execute!'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.3.5/bin/cucumber:13
>   /usr/bin/cucumber:23:in`load'
>   /usr/bin/cucumber:23

If I include PageObject in any of my classes, I receive the following:

> uninitialized constant Home::PageObject (NameError)
>   ./lib/Home.rb:4
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `gem_original_require'
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in`require'
>   /Users/garethbragg/dev/trade-finder/test/cucumber/features/support/env.rb:2
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.3.5/bin/../lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:122:in `load'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.3.5/bin/../lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:122:in`load_code_file'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.3.5/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:180:in `load_file'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.3.5/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in`load_files!'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.3.5/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `each'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.3.5/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in`load_files!'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.3.5/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:183:in `load_step_definitions'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.3.5/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:42:in`run!'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.3.5/bin/../lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:47:in `execute!'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.3.5/bin/cucumber:13
>   /usr/bin/cucumber:23:in`load'
>   /usr/bin/cucumber:23

Any suggestions would be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the error is due to your using ruby 1.8.  Can you give it a try with 1.9 or higher?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - Ive upgraded to Ruby 1.9.3 (ruby-1.9.3-p448), but I'm still having the same issue:  

    /Users/garethbragg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/page-object-0.9.1/lib/page-object/widgets.rb:32: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting '|'
...dget_tag do |name, identifier={:index => 0}, &block|  
                              ^
/Users/garethbragg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/page-object-0.9.1/lib/page-object/widgets.rb:32: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting kEND
...ame, identifier={:index => 0}, &block|

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem earlier today. I fixed it by (as Cheezy suggested), updating my ruby version. (1.9.3).

It is also worth noting that I updated rubygems, deleted my Gemfile.lock, and ran another bundle install. (I'm also using rvm for my ruby versions)